# Define complex property with custom tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-custom-component

Is this possible to pass complex property with custom elemment as follow.

**customcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, forwardRef,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-div',
    template: `<div >
                    Custom Div {{content.value}}
                </div>`
})
export class MyDivComponent {
    @Input() content: any[] = [];
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<custom-div [content]="content"></custom-div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    content:any={};
    constructor(){
        this.content.value ="Compex property";        
    }
}
```

Instead of using like above possible to use like below

**customcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, forwardRef,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-div',
    template: `<div >
        Custom Div {{content.value}}
            </div>`
})
export class MyDivComponent {
    @Input() content: any[] = [];
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<custom-div [content.value]="content"></custom-div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    content:string;
    constructor() {
        this.content="Compex property";    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible. What is the problem?

Comment: is this ppossible to define like **<custom-div [content.value]="content"></custom-div>**

https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Comment: Ok, now I see what the question is. Not, that's not possible.

Comment: @Abinaya How did you provide values for it?

Comment: @Abinaya What is printed in the console

Comment: @RomanC  If i use lik <custom-div [content.value]="content"></custom-div> getting below console error




_Can't bind to 'content.value' since it isn't a known property of 'custom-div'.
1. If 'custom-div' is an Angular component and it has 'content.value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'custom-div' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
    </div>_

Comment: @Abinaya Oh. yeah It always erros. Please add this comment to the question. And print stacktrace (extended)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  it is it not possible to define like this ?

Comment: No, it's not. ,